# PostgreSQL Evolutions: "PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already"

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to set up a dev PostgreSQL server.  It's running and I'm able to create roles, tables, etc. from the command line.  However when I try to apply evolutions using Play, I get the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients already
```

I'm able to connect and if I put in a syntax error on purpose, it returns the syntax error so I know that Play is able to connect to the database.  However, after the evolution is successfully applied I get the error shown above.

I'm not terribly well versed in PostgreSQl administration so I'm not sure if the problem is with Play or my PostgreSQL installation.  I just installed it using Heroku's Postgres.app on a Mac running Mountain Lion.

Here is what gets written to the console:

```
! @6cnb0blpp - Internal server error, for request [GET /] ->

play.api.db.evolutions.InvalidDatabaseRevision: Database 'default' needs evolution! [An SQL script need to be run on your database.]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Evolutions.scala:427) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin.withLock(Evolutions.scala:448) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:414) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1.apply(Evolutions.scala:412) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.4]
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:59) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.3]
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 10. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 9. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 8. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 7. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 6. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 5. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 4. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 3. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 2. Exception: null
[error] c.j.b.h.AbstractConnectionHook - Failed to acquire connection Sleeping for 1000ms and trying again. Attempts left: 1. Exception: null
[error] application -
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the number of connections used by your application. Had the same errors on a mac install. As shown in the [official documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/SettingsJDBC) :

```
db.default.partitionCount=2

# The number of connections to create per partition. Setting this to 
# 5 with 3 partitions means you will have 15 unique connections to the 
# database. Note that BoneCP will not create all these connections in   
# one go but rather start off with minConnectionsPerPartition and 
# gradually increase connections as required.
db.default.maxConnectionsPerPartition=5

# The number of initial connections, per partition.
db.default.minConnectionsPerPartition=5
```

Comment: I've set those settings in my application.conf but I still end up with the same result.  I've connected to PostgreSQL in the past with Play and I've never had this issue, I'm really stumped.

Answer (score 6):

The number of allowed connections is set in `postgresql.conf` with the GUC ("Grand Unified Configuration") [`max_connections`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-MAX-CONNECTIONS). Default is 100.

But before you tinker whit the setting, you must ask yourself: where did all those other 100 connections come from, before your cluster hit the limit? That's usually pointing to a bug in your installation or program!

You may also be interested in [connection pooling](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling#Connection_Pooling_and_Acceleration) and this [article about The Number of Connections](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections) in the Postgres Wiki.

Comment: It's a vanilla Postgres install and a brand-new Play 2.0.4 project.  All I have so far are some models defined. Is there a log I can look in to figure out where the other connections are coming from?

Comment: @Ryan: You can set up PostgreSQL to log pretty much anything. [Start by reading the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-logging.html).

Answer (score 4):

Postgres.app defaults to max_connections = 10. See `~/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var/postgresql.conf`.

I fixed this by increasing max_connections to 50. On Mountain Lion I also had to reduce shared_buffers to 500kB for Postgres to start.